# Generic constructor (Class<T> clazz) do not support T where T is another generics

Tags: java, generics

Imagine this class:

```
public class ObjectCreator<T> {
    private Class<T> persistentClass;

    public ObjectCreator(Class<T> persistentClass) {
        this.persistentClass = persistentClass;
    }

    public T create() {
        T instance = null;
        try {
            instance = persistentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        return instance;
    }
}
```

Now I sublclass it with a domain object:

```
public class PersonCreator extends ObjectCreator<Person>{

    /**
     * @param persistentClass
     */
    public PersonCreator() {
        super(Person.class);

    }

}
```

All works great...
But if I try to subclass it with a another generic domain object the compiler complains:

```
public class MessageCreator extends ObjectCreator<Message<String>>{

    /**
     * @param persistentClass
     */
    public MessageCreator() {
        super(Message.class);
    }

}
```

> The constructor `ObjectCreator<Message<String>>(Class<Message>)` is undefined MessageCreator.java

I think that this is a big limit: why is this forbidden?

Any idea how to work around?

Massimo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
super((Class<Message<String>>) ((Object) Message.class)); //compiles with warning
```

It will be even better if you'll change constructor of base class to

```
public ObjectCreator(Class<? extends T> persistentClass)
```

and then use this in derrived classes:

```
super(new Message<String>(){}.getClass()); //compiles without warning
```

It will compile without warnings

**EDIT**

According to definition of `getClass()` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()

Returns `Class<? extends X>`, where X is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is called. Which means `getClass()` will return `Class<? extends Message>` for `new Message<String>()` and `Class<? extends Message<String>>` for anonymous class `new Message<String>(){}`

Comment: Unless `Message` is `final` or has an inaccessible default constructor.

Comment: @PaulBellora yes, this is a known limitation of this approach. However I don't see any other workarounds that will compile without warning.

Comment: That's the best solution I think. One question: which is the difference between new Message<String>() and new Message<String>(){}?

Comment: @MassimoUgues `new Message<String>(){}` will create an anonymous subclass of `Message<String>`. See detailed explanation above.

Comment: The problem with the anonymous class approach is that this will in fact create instances of this very anonymous class in the create method - which is not likely what you want. More-over in other scenarios (like serialization rather than deserialization) an "instanceof" check is going to fail because it will only recognize the anonymous subclass, but not "raw" Message<String> - classes or other classes implementing Message<String>. So although this is the only simple way to compile without a warning, it should be taken with a grain of salt, because it might not behave the way you expect it to.

Comment: @Sebastian how exactly `instanceof` will fail? Anonymus subclass **is** `Message`, so everything seems to be ok.

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev No - the anonymous subclass is not Message, it just inherits from it - it is a new and different class. This will yield false: `new Message<String>(){}.getClass().isInstance(new Message<String>())` and also this one `new Message<String>(){}.getClass().isInstance(new StringMessage())` if `class StringMessage` extends `Message<String>`.

Comment: @Sebastian well, it's because you calling `isInstance` in reverse order. `new Message<String>.getClass().isInstance(new Message<String>(){})` will return true.

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev :-) It's true that the reversed call yields false, however it changes the meaning completely. The argument to the function is the instance that should be checked. The instance this check is performed on is the `persistentClass` field. In your code even `new Message<Integer>.getClass().isInstance(new Message<String>(){})` yields true so that check is quite useless.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22697/discussion-between-dmitry-zaitsev-and-sebastian)

Answer (score 1):

There is no '.class' variant for generic classes - the information is not available at runtime, hovewever in order to make the above code compile, you can simply cast the expression to the required type.

```
super ((Class<Message<String>>)((Class<?>)Message.class));
```

Note that this will not make the information available at runtime either (i.e. for reflection, etc.), however it should compile with an unchecked warning - which is just that - a warning.

Comment: super ((Class<Message<String>>)((Class<?>)Message.class)); this does

Comment: Sorry, I did not check my answer, first - Leonidos is correct - you first need to cast the Message.class to `Class<?>`and then do the required cast. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you just use

```
public class MessageCreator extends ObjectCreator<Message>{

    /**
     * @param persistentClass
     */
    public MessageCreator() {
        super(Message.class);
    }

}
```

This creates the correct object but still will give a warning for the class definition and if you do

```
Message<String> m = creator.create();
```